# ACF Field not saving data

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

After changing the field value to a new one, it does not save data. I tried update value via function update_field(), but not actions

```
$post_id = 197;

$value = update_field( 'my_field', 'my_value', $post_id );
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use field key instead of field name, 
try this code.

```
$post_id = 197;

//Repace field_56e683ab6265f with your field key
update_field( 'field_56e683ab6265f', 'my_value', $post_id );
```

Or You can also do with this

```
update_post_meta( $post_id , 'my_field', 'my_value' );
//Repace field_56e683ab6265f with your field key
update_post_meta( $post_id , '_my_field', 'field_56e683ab6265f' );
```

Comment: If it's not working with `update_field` we can also do with `update_post_meta`, check my edits